# Inner Exception Error VB.Net when Inserting into database

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to inset data into a sql server database, I have only started using VB this week so I am very new to it.

Here are my table definitions:

```
[betfair_place_bsp](
    [bf_runner_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [bf_event_id] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [win] [int] NOT NULL,
    [bsp_place] [decimal](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ppwap] [decimal](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [early_traded] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [pre_traded] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [meeting_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [scheduled_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [country] [varchar](50) NOT NULL]
```

I am readin the data and then splitting it up by column

```
line = reader.ReadLine
Dim colsArray() As String = Split(line, ",")
```

I change the format of some of the columns

```
Dim meetingDate As String = Split(colsArray(3), " ")(0)
Dim scheduledTime As String = colsArray(3) + ":00"

Dim winLose As Integer = colsArray(6)
Dim backPrice As Decimal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(colsArray(7)), 2)
Dim weightedPrice As Decimal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(colsArray(8)), 2)
Dim earlyTraded As Decimal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(colsArray(14)), 0)
Dim preTraded As Decimal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(colsArray(15)), 0)
```

Then create the insert string

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into betfair_place_bsp values(" + colsArray(4) + "," + "1." + colsArray(0) + ",'" + colsArray(5) + "'," + winLose  _
                    + ",'" + backPrice + "'," + weightedPrice + "," + earlyTraded + "," + preTraded + "," + meetingDate + ",'" + scheduledTime + "' + 'UK')"
```

When I try and tune the above line I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "insert into betfair_place_bsp va" to type 'Double' is not valid.'
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I don't have anything of type 'Double'

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: When you concatenate a numeric value (with decimals) inside a string, the compiler inserts the result of a _ToString_ call for that numeric value. This conversion is affected by your locale settings and could result in a comma used as decimal point. That ends in a invalid numeric value for your db. And the dates have similar problem. If you are still not convinced that concatenating strings is very bad for SQL then you should take a look at what an Sql Injection hack is and then start using parameterized queries as soon as possible.

Comment: Concatenating stings for SQL is very error prone.  Even ignoring the whole sql injection issue , using parameters makes the whole process less painful for you as the developer and worth it

Comment: DO NOT use the addition operator (+) to concatenate strings. Use the concatenation operator (&). If both operands are type `String` then the effect will be the same. If they are not then the system has to decide which operand will be converted and what addition operator will be used. Clearly, you you are adding a `String` and a number and the system is choosing to convert the `String` to a number and perform arithmetic addition, but the conversion fails. If you use the right operator then ONLY concatenation can result. That said, don't use string concatenation to build SQL code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On the advice given above I have used parameters rather than concatenating a string.

```
Dim newDataInsert As New betfair_data() With {.bf_event_id = "1." & colsArray(0), .bf_runner_id = colsArray(4), .name = colsArray(5), .bsp_place = colsArray(7),
                    .ppwap = colsArray(8), .early_traded = colsArray(14), .pre_traded = colsArray(15), .meeting_date = meetingDate, .scheduled_time = scheduledTime, .country = "UK", .win = colsArray(6)
                    }

                db.InsertRow(newDataInsert)
```